# Enter mixed data into MySQL database from array using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array containing values I want to enter into a database. My database is structured like so:
    1 string value, 7 int values, 5 float values, 1 string value.
The data I want to pass to the database is in an array, with proper typing, `$outputArr[]`

I have tried using the following snippets with no success:

```
$escaped_values = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', array_values($outputArr));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$query = "INSERT INTO table(columns) VALUES ($values)
```

`(type)var_export($outputArr[$i])` for each element of `$outputArr` and
    `$query = INSERT INTO table(columns) VALUES ('$Opos0', $Opos1, $Opos2, ... , '$Opos13')`

How can I pass my data into the database while maintaining proper data types?

Entire function as is now written:

```
$outputArr = array();
foreach($numArr as $k1 => $val){
    foreach($val as $k2 => $val2){
        $outputArr[$k2] = $numArr[$k1][$k2];
    }

    $Opos0 = serialize($connect->real_escape_string(var_export($outputArr[0])));
    $Opos1 = serialize((int)var_export($outputArr[1]));
    $Opos2 = serialize((int)var_export($outputArr[2]));
    $Opos3 = serialize((int)var_export($outputArr[3]));
    $Opos4 = serialize((int)var_export($outputArr[4]));
    $Opos5 = serialize((int)var_export($outputArr[5]));
    $Opos6 = serialize((int)var_export($outputArr[6]));
    $Opos7 = serialize((int)var_export($outputArr[7]));
    $Opos8 = serialize((float)var_export($outputArr[8]));
    $Opos9 = serialize((float)var_export($outputArr[9]));
    $Opos10 = serialize((float)var_export($outputArr[10]));
    $Opos11 = serialize((float)var_export($outputArr[11]));
    $Opos12 = serialize((float)var_export($outputArr[12]));
    $Opos13 = serialize($connect->real_escape_string(var_export($outputArr[13])));

    $query = "INSERT INTO `num_data`(`CalledNum`, `NumCalls`, `uniqueCalls`, `dur1sec`, `dur30sec`, `dur60sec`, `dur90sec`, `dur120sec`, 
    `grossIncome`, `cogs`, `split`, `netIncome`, `nipuc`, `CallDate`) VALUES ($Opos0, $Opos1, $Opos2, $Opos3, $Opos4, $Opos5, $Opos6, 
    $Opos7, $Opos8, $Opos9, $Opos10, $Opos11, $Opos12, $Opos13)";
    $result = $connect->query($query);
    if($result == false){
        echo "<p>Error entering data into num_data!</p>";
        echo "<pre>", print_r( $query ), "</pre>";
        die(mysqli_error($connect));
    }
    $k2 = 0;
}   //Parse numArr info into INSERT command.`
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions.  Use PDO or MySQLi and use prepared statements.

Comment: Using `MySQLi` in the program. Thanks for pointing out the copy/paste typo

Comment: Which errors are thrown?

Comment: @visevo Not sure which errors are being thrown, as I'm checking with all I know how to: `if(!($result = mysqli->query($query)))`. My best guess would be incompatible data types between the PHP and database.

Comment: Look at the query that you're trying to execute. Right before `mysqli->query($query)))` do this: `echo "<pre>", print_r( $query ), "</pre>"; die();` and look at the results. There's probably missing data.

Comment: @visevo Spot on. Webpage reports that the strings aren't transferring properly into the query. There's also a 1 right after the closing parentheses. Is that from `print_r()` or `die()`?

Comment: it's from print_r(). If you post your entire function I can help further

Comment: if `$result` is false, then the query failed, and you should `die(mysqli_error($connect))` to get the actual error message. get that, before poking away at random theories. I'll guess that it's an [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability via `$Opos0`, which is a plain strain.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function and store the result as a BLOB field. You can unserialize to get the data back while fetching.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally able to pinpoint errors and figure out an answer to my question/problem.

```php
$Opos0 = $connect->real_escape_string($outputArr[0]);
$Opos1 = (int)($outputArr[1]);
$Opos2 = (int)($outputArr[2]);
$Opos3 = (int)($outputArr[3]);
$Opos4 = (int)($outputArr[4]);
$Opos5 = (int)($outputArr[5]);
$Opos6 = (int)($outputArr[6]);
$Opos7 = (int)($outputArr[7]);
$Opos8 = (float)($outputArr[8]);
$Opos9 = (float)($outputArr[9]);
$Opos10 = (float)($outputArr[10]);
$Opos11 = (float)($outputArr[11]);
$Opos12 = (float)($outputArr[12]);
$Opos13 = $connect->real_escape_string(($outputArr[13]));

$query = "INSERT INTO `num_data`(`CalledNum`, `NumCalls`, `uniqueCalls`, `dur1sec`, `dur30sec`, `dur60sec`, `dur90sec`, `dur120sec`, 
    `grossIncome`, `cogs`, `split`, `netIncome`, `nipuc`, `CallDate`) VALUES ('$Opos0', $Opos1, $Opos2, $Opos3, $Opos4, $Opos5, $Opos6, 
    $Opos7, $Opos8, $Opos9, $Opos10, $Opos11, $Opos12, '$Opos13')";
$result = $connect->query($query);
if($result == false){
    echo "<p>Error entering data into num_data!</p>";
    echo "<pre>", print_r( $query ), "</pre>";
    die(mysqli_error($connect));
}
```

Doesn't feel very pretty, but it works.

Comment: If you're data is not really heavy why not mix all of them in one array and save it in one field?? you have to save it in binary anyway

Comment: If you use the prepare, bind, execute methodology which utilizes parameters and binds the variables to them, you won't have to concern yourself with escaping values.